# How to join table in many-to-many relationship?

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is a simplified version of my problem. I have two tables. Each table has a unique ID field, but it's irrelevant in this case.

**`shipments`** has 3 fields: `shipment_id`, `receive_by_datetime`, and `qty`.

**`deliveries`** has 4 fields: `delivery_id`, `shipment_id`, `delivered_on_datetime`, and `qty`.

In `shipments`, the `shipment_id` and `receive_by_datetime` fields always match up. There are many rows in the table that would appear to be duplicates based off of those two columns (but they aren't... other fields are different).

In `deliveries`, the `shipment_id` matches up to the `shipments` table. There are also many rows that would appear to be duplicates based off of the `delivery_id` and `delivered_on_datetime` fields (but they aren't again... other fields exist that I didn't list).

I am trying to pull one row per aggregate `delivered_on_datetime` and `receive_by_datetime`, but because of the many-to-many relationships, it's difficult. Is a query somewhere along these lines correct?

```
SELECT d.delivered_on_datetime, s.receive_by_datetime, SUM(d.qty)
FROM deliveries d
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT s1.shipment_id, s1.receive_by_datetime
  FROM shipments s1
) s ON (s.shipment_id = d.shipment_id)
GROUP BY d.delivered_on_datetime, s.receive_by_datetime
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, the problem with many-to-many is you get the cartesian product of rows, so you end up counting the same row more than once. Once for each other row it matches against.

> In shipments, the shipment_id and receive_by_datetime fields always match up

If this means there cannot be two shipments with the same ID but different dates then your query will work. But in general it is not safe. i.e. If subselect distinct could return more than one row per shipment ID, you will be subject to the double counting issue. Generically this is a very tricky problem to solve - in fact I see no way it could be with this data model.

Comment: Yes, there can only be one `receive_by_datetime` per `shipment_id`. Thank you Sodved! Let me double-check that this works and I will mark this as correct.

Answer (score 2):

You will run into problems where the total `SUM(d.qty)` will be larger than the value from `SELECT SUM(qty) FROM deliveries`

Something like this might be better suited for you:

```
SELECT d.delivered_on_datetime, s.receive_by_datetime, SUM(d.qty) AS delivered_qty, SUM(d.qty) AS shipped_qty
FROM deliveries d
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT s1.shipment_id, s1.receive_by_datetime, SUM(s1.qty) AS qty
  FROM shipments s1
  GROUP BY s1.shipment_id, s1.received_by_datetime
) s ON (s.shipment_id = d.shipment_id)
GROUP BY d.delivered_on_datetime, s.receive_by_datetime
```

If you somehow have (or might have) a `shipment_id` that has multiple values for `received_by_datetime` and it's best practice to assume that something else might have corrupted the data slightly then to prevent the lines in the `deliveries` table being duplicated while still returning a valid result you can use:

```
SELECT d.delivered_on_datetime, s.receive_by_datetime, SUM(d.qty) AS delivered_qty, SUM(d.qty) AS shipped_qty
FROM deliveries d
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT s1.shipment_id, MAX(s1.receive_by_datetime) AS receive_by_datetime, SUM(s1.qty) AS qty
  FROM shipments s1
  GROUP BY s1.shipment_id
) s ON (s.shipment_id = d.shipment_id)
GROUP BY d.delivered_on_datetime, s.receive_by_datetime
```

Comment: inner select should be `SELECT s1.shipment_id, s1.receive_by_datetime, SUM(qty) as qty` instead of `SELECT s1.shipment_id, s1.receive_by_datetime, SUM(qty)`

Comment: true, thanks for that, didn't proof read it. It's easy to forget that sub queries must all define (unique) names.

Comment: Thanks, Seph. The problem is that I'm looking to pull `SUM(d.qty)`, not `SUM(s.qty)`. I want to make sure that the `LEFT JOIN` doesn't give me more than one row for each `shipment_id`, or else the sum would be too high (by a factor of how many `s1` rows there are. Does that make sense?

Comment: is `shipment_id` unique in the `shipments` table, or is `receive_by_datetime` always the exact same value for a given `shipment_id`? If that's the case then you don't have a "many-to-many" relationship instead you have a "many-to-one" (or maybe even a "one-to-one") relationship and the answer is as as have in the original question or my answer with `SUM(d.qty)` in the top line.

Comment: Further to that, if you want only one row, and a delivery has `shipment` with multiple `receive_by_datetime` somehow (for example data is in the middle of being updated outside a transaction), then you will need to work out how you want to count it - Would you want to just use the lowest, highest or average value `receive_by_datetime` for a given `shipment_id`? I've updated my question with a second example for this

Comment: Hey Seph, I appreciate your help. There are multiple rows for each identical `shipment_id`/`receive_by_datetime` pair in the `shipments` database.